# Make all values appear when clearing "input field" text area feature

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am using the "input field" text area feature on Spotfire. When I input a value, data shows up. However, when I clear out the text area box, all the data disappears. How do I make a default view with ALL of the values showing when I clear the input field?

Image attached
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHOkU.png)